# Adding a location bar shortcut for sending a new mail (via Gmail)?

Tags: firefox

Is there a way that I can type a command in location bar and the browser will open the "new mail interface" in the current tab.

So, we don't have to go to gmail and click on compose button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works...

```
     https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1
```

You can actually start filling in the email too...

```
     https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1&to=ToEmailAddress@here.com&su=SubjectURLEscaped&body=BodyTextURLEscaped
```

Cheers!